# Structuring JSON object for iterative component with Handlebars (HTML) to create 3 levels of related content

Tags: javascript, html, json, handlebars.js

I'm creating a mega menu component - which is basically taking the format of 3 levels of content.

L1s: displayed horizontally in a "typical" navbar (that when hovered on expand mega menu)

L2: Should be "children" of L1 and the parent of L3. (displayed in a vertical list on the left side of mega-menu)

L3: Displayed as `figure`s with an img and caption

I've put together the below JSON object in attempt to make this component data driven (static content won't work for my use case):

```
{
    "desktopL1s": [{
            "label": "Level 1 Heading 1"
        },
        {
            "label": "Level 1 Heading 2"
        },
        {
            "label": "Level 1 Heading 3"
        },
        {
            "label": "Level 1 Heading 4"
        },
        {
            "label": "Level 1 Heading 5"
        }
    ],
    "desktopL2s": [{
    "label": "Level 2 Item 1",
    "desktopL3s": [{
        "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image1.png",
        "caption": "Level 3 Child 1"
      },
      {
        "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image2.png",
        "caption": "Level 3 Child 2"
      },
      {
        "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image3.png",
        "caption": "Level 3 Child 3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Level 2 Item 2",
    "desktopL3s": [{
      "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image4.png",
      "caption": "Level 3 Child 1"
    },
    {
      "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image5.png",
      "caption": "Level 3 Child 2"
    }
  ]
  }
 ]
}
```

And the following HTML using Handlebars to iterate through the various elements of my code:

```
  <div class="desktop-navigation d-none d-lg-block">
    <ul
      class="nav-menu d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center"
    >
      {{#each this.desktopL1s}}
      <li id="{{id}}">
        <a href="#">{{label}} </a>
      </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>

    <div class="mega-menu">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="content-links col-md-3">
          <ul>
            {{#each this.desktopL2s}}
            <li><a href="#">{{label}}</a></li>
            {{/each}}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 content-panel">
          <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
            {{#each this.desktopL3s}}
            <figure>
              <a href="#"
                ><img class="content-square" src="{{imgSrc}}" alt="{{altText}}"
              /></a>
              <figcaption>{{caption}}</figcaption>
            </figure>
            {{/each}}
          </div>
          <button class="close-btn-desktop">
            <img src="../../assets/cross.svg" alt="close-icon-desktop" />
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-tertiary" type="button">
            Explore level 2 content
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can anyone advise as to how better structure my JSON so that an actual relationship exists between the 3 levels. L1s has been slightly abstracted as it sits in a different `div` than the actual mega menu but some pointers on how to properly structure this would be really appreciated.

EDIT: I have attached how the markup renders, which hopefully provides an insight into the relationship of each level:

[image: How the mega menu renders]

Comment: I think it is hard to advise without seeing how you intend this to be rendered. Generally speaking, if lists are children of list-items, you would put the child `<ul>` within the parent `<li>`.

Comment: For example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/5fdp3tzb/

Comment: Thanks for your response, the intention is that the markup remains unchanged. So the content links (L2s) and content panel (L3s) should be in two columns (side by side). The snippet included above changes the markup which then no longer aligns with the desired UX.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: hey, I've added an image of how the markup is rendered to hopefully give a better understanding of the problem.

Each L1 item has children (content-links) and each of those L2s have their own children (content-square) which are currently rendered in the content-panel. I'm using a grid layout to position the L3's to the right of the L2's hence why in the markup L2 and L3 are sibling divs.

Comment: Perhaps something like this?: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/0c2tfj6g/

Comment: This is so helpful, and is completely on the correct lines of what I'm looking for. A final question I have which probably feeds into the original question: managing the relationship between these items, for example, only the L3's that are children of the selected L2 should be visible at any given time, but currently, all L3's are visible regardless of the L2 selected?

Comment: So, when I'm hovering on an L2, I should only expect to see the L3 (children) of that item. And so on as I hover over the different L2s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can structure your JSON so as to mirror the relationship of your objects. For example:

```
{
  "desktopL1s": [
    {
      "label": "Label 1",
      "desktopL2s": [
        {
          "label": "Label 1 > Label 2",
          "desktopL3s": [
            {
              "caption": "Label 1 > Label 2 > Label 3"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can then use nested `{{#each}}` loops in your template to render each level of navigation.

The more challenging part is creating the mouse event handlers to show/hide the navigation items. One way you could do it is to create identifiers for each nav item based on its index and the index of each of its ancestors.

The top level nav items would be like: `['0', '1', '2']`.

The items on subsequent levels would use a separator, like `_`, to separate their own index from their parent's: `['0_0', '0_1', '1_0', '1_1', '2_0', '2_1']`.

The third-level would follow the pattern.

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('Template').innerHTML);

const data = {
  "desktopL1s": [
    {
      "label": "Level 1 Heading 1",
      "desktopL2s": [
        {
          "label": "Heading 1 > Level 2 > Item 1",
          "desktopL3s": [
            {
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image1.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 1"
            },
            {
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image2.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 2"
            },
            {
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image3.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "Heading 1 > Level 2 Item 2",
          "desktopL3s": [
            {
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image4.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 1"
            },
            {
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image5.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Level 1 Heading 2",
      "desktopL2s": [
        {
          "label": "Heading 2 > Level 2 > Item 1",
          "desktopL3s": [
            {
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image1.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 1"
            },
            {
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image2.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 2"
            },
            {
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image3.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "Heading 2 > Level 2 Item 2",
          "desktopL3s": [
            {
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image4.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 1"
            },
            {
              "imgSrc": "../../assets/images/mega-menu/image5.png",
              "caption": "Level 3 Child 2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Level 1 Heading 3",
      "desktopL2s": []
    },
    {
      "label": "Level 1 Heading 4",
      "desktopL2s": []
    },
    {
      "label": "Level 1 Heading 5",
      "desktopL2s": []
    }
  ]
};

const output = template(data);

document.body.innerHTML = output;

$('[data-id]').on('mouseenter', function () {
  const $this = $(this);
  const targetId = String($this.data('id'));
  const targetParts = targetId.split('_');
  const targetLevel = targetParts.length - 1;
  
  $('[data-id]').each(function () {
    const $this = $(this);
    const id = String($this.data('id'));
    const parts = id.split('_');
    const level = parts.length - 1;
    // don't affect items on a lower-level
    if (level <= targetLevel) { return; }
    
    // show items on the level 1 higher than the target
    // whose id starts with the id of the target
    const isToShow = level === (targetLevel + 1) && id.startsWith(targetId);
    
    $this.toggle(isToShow);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.mega-menu {
  background: azure;
  border: 1px solid aquamarine;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-menu li {
  background: coral;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.nav-level-2 {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-level-2 li {
  background: darkkhaki;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.nav-level-3 {
  background: palegreen;
  display: none;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.content-links {
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 0 0 33.3%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="Template" type="text/template">
  <div class="desktop-navigation d-none d-lg-block">
    <ul
      class="nav-menu d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center"
    >
      {{#each this.desktopL1s}}
        <li id="{{id}}" data-id="{{@index}}">
          <a href="#">[{{@index}}] {{label}}</a>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>

    <div class="mega-menu">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="content-links col-md-3">
            <ul class="nav-level-2">
                {{#each this.desktopL1s}}
                    {{#each this.desktopL2s}}
                <li data-id="{{@../index}}_{{@index}}"><a href="#">[{{@../index}}_{{@index}}] {{label}}</a></li>
                {{/each}}
             {{/each}}
         </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 content-panel">
          <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
            {{#each this.desktopL1s}}
                {{#each this.desktopL2s}}
                {{#each this.desktopL3s}}
                  <figure class="nav-level-3" data-id="{{@../../index}}_{{@../index}}_{{@index}}">
                    <a href="#"
                      ><img class="content-square" src="{{imgSrc}}" alt="{{altText}}"
                    /></a>
                    <figcaption>[{{@../../index}}_{{@../index}}_{{@index}}]{{caption}}</figcaption>
                  </figure>
                {{/each}}
                {{/each}}
            {{/each}}
          </div>
          <button class="close-btn-desktop">
            <img src="../../assets/cross.svg" alt="close-icon-desktop" />
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-tertiary" type="button">
            Explore level 2 content
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```